# Which kind of object should i use for a once-per-5-minute check program?

Tags: android

I'm about to create a little Android program which performs a small task every say 5 minutes. 
Then the program can 'stop' and wait for anther 5 minutes and perform the same small task.

I call this program the 'service'

I should be able to communicate with the program (can be via a setting  if that is possible, or talking directly to the service) via another application (or can it be the same?) which has a small UI to set some settings for the small activity.

Now I've read about these constructs, and I'm not sure which one to use:

1. Service
2. IntentService
3. AlarmManager
4. Handler

Can you shine a light on whic one to use?

Ps

I can imagine my description of the goal is a little hard to understand. Best thing to compare it to I think is the icon tray on a windows pc: it's a program/service which starts automaticly and does some things (in my case, it does the things periodically) and you can have some interaction with it when you click the icon. So my program must be running uin the background, but I must be able to communicate with the program.

EDIT
Maybe a better example is this: there is a program/service that checks wether there are new WiFi  networks available near your phone. That service checks periodically (i guess) for the presence of new networks. You can however turn off this behaviour via a setting (which is what i mean with the GUI interacting with the service)

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing exactly what the tasks you're performing are, I'm going to say you need to use `AlarmManager` to manage the timing of the tasks, an `IntentService` to run the tasks themselves.

Seems like you just want the user to be able to set preferences on the service?  You'd use an `Activity` for that, saving the settings using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), which your service could read from.

Comment: Is the AlarmManager a kind of program, or is it an object i create IN an Android Application. (and the same question for the IntentService ;-))

Comment: You extend IntentService with your own service.  AlarmManager is an object you get from Android by using ` Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)` and then use that object to set alarms.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use both the `AlarmManager` and `IntentService`. that way you start the alarm and every 5 min or whatever you send an intent to the intent service to do whatever you want to do.

The intent service will stop itself once all tasks are done so you dont have to worry about managing it

Comment: Is there a way of have a GUI for one of them, to set some settings/preferences?

Comment: services dont have a UI, that is what an activity is for. create something to chnage your settings (PreferenceActivity/PreferenceFragment) and save the settings in shared preferences. those preferences you can access in your service

Answer (score 1):

Here's the difference between these:

Service-  runs permanently (or until stopped due to resources).  Does not keep the phone awake.  Is not scheduled, must see some event occur or be called in order to do work.

IntentService- runs long enough to do a task.  Can queue up several tasks.  Does not keep the phone awake.  Is not scheduled, but does queue up requests.

AlarmManager- Must exist in the context of an Activity or Service.  Will wake up the phone.  Runs on a schedule.

Handler-  runs when an event comes in.  Does not keep the phone awake.  Can be scheduled, but because it will not wake the phone should only be used for a short term delay.

You need an AlarmManager and a Service.  The Service will run and allow your Alarm somewhere to live.  The alarm itself will be called on a schedule and will wake up the phone to do its task.

Comment: What do you mean by 'wake up the telephone'? If i set the phone to 'vibrate' instead of 'ringtone' or in my service shut-off WiFi do i then 'wake up the telephone' ?

Comment: When your screen is off, the phone is asleep.  Apps don't run, activites don't run, services don't run.  There's 2 ways to circumvent that.  One is to take a wakelock-  a wakelock can force either the screen to turn on or just the CPU (to allow your app to run).  The other is to have code in a BroadcastReceiver (like an alarm is) that receives an event-  this code will run even if the phone is asleep.